# Autonomous powered RAM units

Tags: memory, power-supply, power

We all know that RAM is alive only when it is supplied by power, because the data need to be refreshed every couple of milliseconds. My question is, if there are any RAM units for regular PC's that have some kind of "autonomous" power system (battery or other power supply) which is independent of the power output of the whole computer.

Comment: Good question, there's a patent for it http://www.google.com/patents/US7836339

Comment: [Here's one such product](http://www.agigatech.com/agigaram.php)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, that appears to be more of a UPS for RAM...

Comment: @AthomSfere: Yes, a UPS is an autonomous power system run by a battery.

Comment: is this just out of curiosity? or do have a problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some devices such as ACARD ANS-9010 DDR2 SATA RAM-Drive that have autonomus power for RAM.

The idea was to have a hard drive made from volitile ram and be able to store your OS on and features an onboard rechargable battery. 
[image: Acard]

There is also the iram with similar concept in battery use.

Not sure these are still in circulation or not, the idea is several years old and seems to have died with the availablility of the SSD.

[image: iram]

Answer (score 2):

RAM is useless outside of a von Neumann machine, so I would imagine any autonomous RAM system would only serve to test the RAM, and would therefore need a CPU and I/O devices... a typical computer.